# How to calculate avgPreviousExecutionMs for a job in google bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In the [performanceInsights](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#performanceinsights) of bigquery there is one field called avgPreviousExecutionMs, In the description, it was given as like this

**Output only. Average execution ms of previous runs. Indicates the job ran slow compared to previous executions. To find previous executions, use INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables and filter jobs with the same query hash.**

I tried to validate this **avgPreviousExecutionMs** data for one of my jobs based on the views in the [information schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) by filtering the queries with the same hash based on the **query_info.query_hashes.normalized_literals** field.

Steps that I have done to validate this info.

- I ran a job on the flat rate pricing concurrently with other queries, to make it slower such that I can get the avgPreviousExecutionMs field in the [PerformanceInsights](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#performanceinsights) section.
- Now I want to validate this field with the information schema data
- I ran this query in the information schema, by excluding my current job id

  SELECT
  AVG(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)) as avg_duration
  FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER where query_info.query_hashes.
  normalized_literals = "myqueryHash" and job_id != "myjobId";
- The result of the query and the avgPreviousExecutionMs value shown for that job in this [section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#performanceinsights) are not matching.
- How can we validate this info ?
- the [avgPreviousExecutionMs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#performanceinsights) is based on taking the how much time
  period of data.
- This average is based on the [JOBS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) view or [JOBS_BY_USER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-by-user) view or [JOBS_BY_FOLDER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-by-folder) or [JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-by-organization)

Comment: Could you provide the output you are getting and the expected output?

Comment: The output is nothing but duration only, there is a difference of around 300ms for my case, it might vary from case to case

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.